# \href urlbordercolor not visible in pdf

Tags: color, urls, href

I am trying to put a colored border around links but have not been successful so far.
Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% colored links
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,%set true if you want colored links
    linktoc=all,
    %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
    filecolor=black,
    citecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    urlbordercolor = red,
    %linktocpage, 
    %only link the page numbers and not the entire table    of contents
}

\begin{document}
test this is my url: \href{https://www.google.com/}{Google}
\end{document}
```

The resulting pdf looks like that:
[image: Result: linkcolor=blue is applied, urlbordercolor = red is not.]

What can I do to fix that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could it be the spaces around `=`?

Comment: @mickep thanks for your comment. Unfortunately that's not it, I just tried it without the spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hyperref disables the border, if you use colorlinks as both is a bit overdoing. You can reactivate it with `\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 1}}`:

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% colored links
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,%set true if you want colored links
    linktoc=all,
    %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
    filecolor=black,
    citecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    urlbordercolor = red,
    %linktocpage, 
    %only link the page numbers and not the entire table    of contents
}
\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 1}}
\begin{document}

test this is my url: \href{https://www.google.com/}{Google}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Ulrike Fischer!